# why same images are appearing while im scrolling my tabelview cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[enclosureUrlArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        ([self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            cell.tag = indexPath.row;
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            cell.IMGLabel.image = image;
            [cell.IMGLabel setImage:image];
            [cell.IMGLabel.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
            [cell.IMGLabel.layer setCornerRadius:2.5f];
            [cell setNeedsLayout];


        });
    });
```

Comment: Cells are reused. You start loading the image for a cell, and then that cell scrolls out of view.  The cell is then reused for another row and you start loading the image for *that* cell.  Meanwhile the previous fetch completes and you update the cell (which is now for, say row 5) with the image for row 1.  The other problem (although you haven't shown your full `cellForRowAtIndexPath so it is just a guess) is that when you reuse the cell you don't set the imagview image to nil or a placeholder, so it will have whatever image it last had until the fetch completes.  Look at using SDWebImage

Comment: thank u sdwebimage is working fine

Comment: maybe you can show the cellForRow implementation?